# Delete rows based on first occurence of value in R

Tags: r, row

so I have this issue with row deletion. What I'm after is something that will delete rows AFTER the FIRST occurrence of the value **1** in df$C. This needs to happen for every value in df$A and every value in df$B, if that's clear.  Below is an example of the df. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
A B C
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 2 0
1 2 1
2 1 0
2 1 1
2 1 0
```

Comment: With your example data, what is the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retain rows up to first occurrence of a value in a column, by group. Groups without value allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734831/retain-rows-up-to-first-occurrence-of-a-value-in-a-column-by-group-groups-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer to your problem is using the which statement...

```
new.df=my.df[1:which(my.df$C==1)[1],]
```

In this way you can then check for logical operations on your data

Comment: this does not retain by group - which the OP asked for: "This needs to happen for every value in df$A and every value in df$B, etc "

Answer (score 1):

Lets create your data.frame:

```
my.df <- read.table(text="A B C
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 0
1 1 0
1 2 0
1 2 1
2 1 0
2 1 1
2 1 0", header=TRUE)
```

Lets find the first match of 1 in the column C. `match` finds the first position of occurence, so I hope it does not go through the all column searching for 1s (but i did not check if that is true).

```
WhereAreYou <- match(1, my.df$C)
```

And now lets subset the initial data.frame.

```
new.df <- my.df[1:WhereAreYou, ]
```

We're selecting the rows from 1 to WhereAreyou, and all the columns.

Comment: This doesn't quite sound like what they are asking for.

Comment: Well.. it does what I think they are asking for =p If the OP clarifies his expected result maybe i can improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

A little cleaner:

```
keep <- with(mydf, {
  keeper <- tapply(C, list(A, B), FUN = function(x) {
    n <- rep(0, length(x))
    n[1:(which(x == 1)[1])] <- 1
    n
  })
  as.logical(unlist(keeper))
})
mydf[keep, ]
#    A B C
# 1  1 1 0
# 2  1 1 0
# 3  1 1 1
# 6  1 2 0
# 7  1 2 1
# 9  2 1 1
# 10 2 1 0
```

#### Original

Here's sort of a clumsy way to do what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
mydf$rn <- 1:nrow(mydf)
out <- do.call(rbind, 
               by(mydf, mydf[1:2], FUN=function(x) 
                 x[1:(which(x$C == 1)[1]), ]))

out[order(out$rn), ]
#   A B C rn
# 1 1 1 0  1
# 2 1 1 0  2
# 3 1 1 1  3
# 6 1 2 0  6
# 7 1 2 1  7
# 8 2 1 0  8
# 9 2 1 1  9
```

The basic assumption here is that when you write *"This needs to happen for every value in `df$A` and every value in `df$B`"*, you are treating columns A and B as grouping variables in some way (in this case with the unique groups of "1, 1", "1, 2", and "2, 1".

Notice that rows 4, 5, and 10 have been dropped. The "rn" column was created to be able to conveniently sort the output later on otherwise retaining the original row orders.