# Retain rows up to first occurrence of a value in a column, by group. Groups without value allowed

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this one:

```
> df
  id type
1  1    a
2  1    a
3  1    b
4  1    a
5  1    b
6  2    a
7  2    a
8  2    b
9  3    a
10 3    a
```

I want to keep all rows for each group (id) up to the first occurrence of value 'b' in the type column. For groups without type 'b', I want to keep all their rows.

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
> dfnew
  id type
1  1    a
2  1    a
3  1    b
4  2    a
5  2    a
6  2    b
7  3    a
8  3    a
```

I tried the following code, but it retains additional rows that have the value 'a' beyond the first occurrence of 'b', and only excludes additional occurrences of 'b', which is not what I want. Look at row 4 in the following. I want to rid of it.

```
> df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(cumsum(type == 'b') <= 1)
Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
Groups: id

  id type
1  1    a
2  1    a
3  1    b
4  1    a
5  2    a
6  2    a
7  2    b
8  3    a
9  3    a
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could combine `match` or `which` with `slice` or (as mentioned by @Richard) `which.max`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(if(any(type == "b")) 1:which.max(type == "b") else row_number())    
# Source: local data table [8 x 2]
# Groups: id
# 
#   id type
# 1  1    a
# 2  1    a
# 3  1    b
# 4  2    a
# 5  2    a
# 6  2    b
# 7  3    a
# 8  3    a
```

---

Or you could try it with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(any(type == "b")) .SD[1:which.max(type == "b")] else .SD, by = id]
#    id type
# 1:  1    a
# 2:  1    a
# 3:  1    b
# 4:  2    a
# 5:  2    a
# 6:  2    b
# 7:  3    a
# 8:  3    a
```

Comment: Or just `which.max()`

Comment: I get this error on my data frame: Error: NA/NaN argument. Reason I believe is because not all 'groups' have the type == 'b'.

Comment: You won't get that error with `slice(1:which.max(type == "b"))`, though what is your desired output in such case?

Comment: I modified my question based on this use case and desired output. The command I was using handled this case right, but not the exclusion of rows occurring after type 'b' is encountered. I will try which.max().

Comment: Ok, see my edit and another solution using `data.table`